# in azure ad b2c is there any way of knowing if the user opted for the keep me signed in option

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

the session behavior is configured. i would want to auto log in or log out basis the session expiry. that cookie is stored under the b2c policy endpoints. if the user does not go for the keep me signed in option, this calculation can be carried out and persisted in local storage. how can i know what option has user chosen. if keep me signed in was checked then the cookie will expire in the configured keep me signed in value else in the web app session timeout configured value - bounded or rolling. all replies seem to focus on configuring session behavior.  need help on knowing what option the user went for - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a claims resolver and issue the Boolean for KMSI into the token. Only works for custom policies.
You can’t do it for user flows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#context