# How to verify that user has selected Keep Me Signed In in Azure AD B2C

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have a React app that authenticates users via Azure B2C (User flow) with Keep Me Signed In possibility. To connect with Azure B2C I am using MSAL.

The app needs to know if user has selected Keep me signed in, because depending on that it has to make some decisions about logging out.

Is there any possibility to check whether user has selected Keep Me Signed In? I didn’t find anything in the MSAL library, what could be useful. There is an expiration date in the cookie, but as far as I know it is impossible to get expiration time with Javascript.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67464959/in-azure-ad-b2c-is-there-any-way-of-knowing-if-the-user-opted-for-the-keep-me-si

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is, that I’m not using custom policy, but standard user flow.